# Understanding slow Django performance

Tags: python, django, http, gunicorn, uvicorn

My webserver is scaling and I'm using Sentry Performance to try and better understand where things are slow. One thing that I don't quite understand is where the slowness might be coming from when the total reported query times are dramatically different than the time it takes to get a response.

For example, one of my endpoints is taking 40s to finally get a response to the user. You'll see the total response time took an incredible 44,000ms even though all the work was done in about 1s (which is still slow, but not 44s slow).

Edit: as a general note, all of my endpoints are doing this– the peculiar thing is those dashed dots at the end of the timeline where any of the actual Django / database hits begin. It just sits blank for a whole minute before Django begins doing anything. Is this a potential guincorn or Uvicorn configuration error?

Additional info:

- Running gunicorn w/ uvicorn: `poetry run gunicorn -w 17 myApp.asgi:application -k myApp.uvicorn.AppUvicornWorker --log-level=debug`
- I'm getting about a hundred requests a second, which the server should be more than able to handle– it has 32gb of ram and 8 cpu cores.

AppUvicornWorker:

```
class AppUvicornWorker(UvicornWorker):
    CONFIG_KWARGS = {"loop": "uvloop", "http": "httptools", "lifespan": "off"}
```

- Views are just basic, completely standard Django Rest Framework ListViewSets queried:

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "name"]

class CommentSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ["id", "text", "user"]


class CommentsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Comments.objects.all()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

[image]

Comment: What does this endpoint do? Can you share the code for it and a description?

Comment: @IainShelvington Actually, all of my endpoints are doing this. This endpoint just queries a table (with minimally nested foreign keys) and returns the results.

Comment: Can you share a view (and template) that takes long. Probably we can help you analyze where the bottleneck(s) are and then you can adapt the other views yourself.

Comment: Your app is async and running in an ASGI server? How many concurrent requests are you getting, how many workers/servers are you running and can you share an example of a view and how you execute your DB queries?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks, I've left more details. Most of my templates are actually entirely standard DRF viewsets. While my view itself is slow (500ms) it looks like on the timeline the view logic never even gets touched for 40s.

Comment: @arooo: can you add the `CommentSerializer` as well?

Comment: @aroooo you have 17 workers handling 100 requests a second and each request is taking over a second?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yeah, this is why I suspect something is wrong with the configuration. I have one other suspicion: I have one endpoint that takes a few-megabyte filefield and was wondering if that was hanging the webserver somehow. It's called a lot because it provides a diff of hashed contacts (from the client) for users who opt into contact finding.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added the serializer.

Comment: @aroooo well one quick speed up would be to add `select_related` to your queryset: `queryset = Comments.objects.all().select_related('user')`

Comment: @aroooo if each request takes over a second it's an issue with your app, your server can't handle that many requests if they all take that long. You would need something like 100 workers to handle that load if your DB could handle that...

Comment: @IainShelvington I see– that makes sense. I'll add the select_related. I replaced the image above to make it a bit easier to understand. Those two brackets on the graph represent my viewing timeframe– and those tiny vertical dots represent the only time Django and the DB are doing anything. All the blank space is the server not doing anything. So this looks like a resource issue in that case?

Comment: @aroooo each async worker will only process one request at a time in the event loop, that wait is probably the length of time the request sits in the queue until it's processed by the worker

Comment: @IainShelvington Wow– I'm just surprised at how resource hungry it is to process this amount of tps. Does my gunicorn start options look correct? Also, could a file upload block an entire worker until the upload is complete?

Comment: @aroooo Yes it would block the worker until it was complete. Is there a reason you are using ASGI when you don't appear to have any async views?

Comment: @IainShelvington I do have some async things going on– in some views we call things like the azure image search API. We were originally using monkey patched gevent which was throwing a bunch of "This operation would block forever" errors.  I switched to Uvicorn because I thought it would help with these async calls but I don't know enough about this process to be sure.

Comment: @IainShelvington (Am I incorrect that using an asgi server would help with these things?)

Comment: @aroooo Did you figure this out? Having a very similar issue with exact setup. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons that this is slow is because for each `Comment`, it has to make a separate query to fetch the `User` data. You can boost efficiency with [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
class CommentsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Comments.objects.select_related('user')
        serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This will retrieve the data of the `user` in the same query, and thus prevent the *N+1* query problem.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Comment` instead of <s>`Comments`</s>.

Comment: This is helpful for reducing the fetch time, but let me add a closer view of the timeline above. You'll see the db query itself only takes 500ms (which I should indeed improve), but for some reason there's a whole 40,000ms before we ever touch the Django view, then the db query.

Comment: @aroooo: likely because the view is constantly waiting for the database to reply and vice versa. So the *CPU-time* of the view is indeed marginal, since it is *pingponging* with the database. For 99 comments, this will require 100 queries to the database, whereas with `.select_related(..)`, it will only perform *one* query.

Comment: Actually, one more detail on another trace: it looks like my entire db fetch call is only 50ms. The Django middleware is never hit for 30 seconds. Wouldn't the middleware be the first thing hit in every scenario?